# Char array representation in memory

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to perform bitwise operations on a char array, as if it were an int, essentially treating bytes like a contiguous area in memory. The code below illustrates my problem.

```
char *cstr = new char[5];
std::strcpy(cstr, "abcd");  

int *p = (int *)(void *)cstr;
std::cout << *p << " " << p << "\n";
std::cout << cstr << " " << (void *)cstr << "\n";
std::cout << sizeof(*p) << "\n";

(*p)++;
std::cout << *p << " " << p << "\n";
std::cout << cstr << " " << (void *)cstr << "\n";
```

The following output is produced:

```
1684234849 0x55f046e7de70
abcd 0x55f046e7de70
4
1684234850 0x55f046e7de70
bbcd 0x55f046e7de70
```

Quick explanation of the code and how it works (to my understanding):

I initialize cstr with "abcd"

```
char *cstr = new char[5];
std::strcpy(cstr, "abcd");
```

I point p to the address of cstr and specify that I want it to be an int

```
int *p = (int *)(void *)cstr;
```

I test that p is pointing where it should and that it occupies 4 bytes

```
std::cout << *p << " " << p << "\n";
std::cout << cstr << " " << (void *)cstr << "\n";
std::cout << sizeof(*p) << "\n";
```

I then increment the integer at the address p is pointing to

```
(*p)++;
```

So now, since "abcd" is a contiguous block of 32 bits in memory, incrementing by 1 should produce "abce". Instead, the code increments the integer successfully, but leaves the char array as "bbce". This last part checks the new values of the integer and cstr

```
std::cout << *p << " " << p << "\n";
std::cout << cstr << " " << (void *)cstr << "\n"
```

Is this expected behavior?

PS: I compiled the code on a linux machine using this command: g++ main.cpp -o main.

```
file main
```

produces the following output: "1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0"

Comment: This is platform dependent.  Many CPUs are little [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), meaning that less significant bytes are stored at lower addresses than more significant bytes.  On such a CPU `bbce` is the expected output.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: Strict Aliasing ensures that any object can be seen as an array of bytes, but it does not guarantee that an array of bytes can be seen as anything other than an array of bytes.

Comment: You're making assumptions that are not (necessarily) true.   `sizeof(int)` is also not necessarily `4`.   You are also assuming the host system is big endian, but it appears your system is little-endian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x86-64 CPUs (like yours) store the least significant byte of multi-byte integers at the lowest memory address. So incrementing the integer that "abcd" corresponds to results in incrementing its least-significant byte, which is stored first in memory. This converted the "a" character into a "b". How code like this behaves is very dependent on how the CPU encodes integers and strings and your expectations of what this code will do have to take those details into account.

To expect the string "abce", you have to make lots of assumptions:

1. You have to expect integers to occupy 4 bytes.
2. You have to expect the least significant byte to be stored last.
3. You have to expect the encoding of the character "e" to be one more than the encoding of the character "d".
4. You have to expect that incrementing a "d" to an "e" won't overflow when viewed as a signed integer increment.

Some of these are reasonable assumptions and some of them aren't, but unless you have reasonable grounds for all these assumptions, your expectation isn't justified.

> Is this expected behavior?

It is what people familiar with your platform would expect. But generally it's easy to avoid relying on these kinds of assumptions and so the best advice is not to rely on them. Assumption 3 is often unavoidable and reasonable on all modern platforms.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about endianness.